# jQuery DataTables customize search box behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, search-box

I want to customize **searchbox** behavior of a table with jQuery DataTables

when searching, rows excluded from search must be set with a "`display='none'`" style hidden and not removed from HTML because I still want to access (from js) elements inside excluded row (like checkbox or input etc.)

Is it possible?

Comment: `tableObj.fnGetNodes()` should give you all rows, exclude the ones in display and do whatever you want with the rest. NOTE:This will work for datatables without serverside processing

Comment: you are right but i need that DOM elements remain in the page
because the datatable was added after to add "ajax" filter capability to the table....but then the form must be submitted and receiving page use request.getParameters('') to get checkbox or input values.....

and there are also many JS functions that already "makes things" to DOM elements....i cannot change the whole code....

Comment: Datatables doesnt put all the elements in dom.

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

jQuery DataTables internally removes non-visible rows from DOM.

But you can access all elements even those that do not exist in DOM with [`$()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/%24%28%29) API method.

**Example:** Set background color for all cells in 4th column.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table
    .$('td:eq(3)')
    .css('background-color', 'red');
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtb7ot50/) for code and demonstration.